# Calculate button height of keyboard buttons

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm working on a universal keyboard extension. Currently I want to calculate the height of a single button. The keyboard has 4 rows as the normal iOS keyboard. Because the space between the buttons (y distance) is 5 I calculated: `(self.view.frame.height-(5*5))/4` 5x5 because the distance to the top and the bottom is included. Now, if I run the app, one button isn't around 1/4 of the screen. Instead the button's height is around 2/3 of the keyboard view. I really can't find my mistake. I hope you can help me with this calculation.

My current code:

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    print((self.view.frame.height-25)/4)
    addButtons()
}

func addButtons() {

    let buttonHeigth = (self.view.frame.height-25)/4
    let button = ResizableButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(5), y: CGFloat(10), width: CGFloat(button.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(buttonHeigth))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(keyPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.scrollView.addSubview(button)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

override func textWillChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

override func textDidChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    var textColor: UIColor
    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.dark {
        textColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        textColor = UIColor.black
    }
    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, for: [])
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, your math seems incorrect... What is 5x5 supposed to signify?

Comment: @LyndseyScott You can also say: `(self.view.frame.height-25)/4`. The -25 is the space between the button (y-axis) and shouldn't be included in the calculation of the button height.

Comment: And this code is executed within your custom keyboard's class after it's laid out its subviews?

Comment: Yes, I call this code with `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: And how are you setting the button heights? If you print out the result of (self.view.frame.height-(5*5))/4 in your view did layout subviews, does it seem consistent with what you're seeing once setting the button height?

Comment: If I say `print((self.view.frame.height-25)/4)`in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` I get 177.75. I'm running on an iPhone 6s Plus.  This is how I set my button height for the first button: `button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(5), y: CGFloat(10), width: CGFloat(button.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(buttonHeigth))`

Comment: The height of an iPhone 6 is 736 and 177.75 = (736-25)/4, so self.view.frame = the height of your entire screen at the place/time you're attempting to retrieve that value. So you're definitely asking for self.view.frame at the wrong time/in the wrong place. Are you absolutely sure you're asking for it within the custom keyboard's class? And viewDidLayoutSubviews can be called multiple times.. Are you taking that into account? If you want me to take a look at your full code, I can.

Comment: Yes, it's in the keyboard class. No, I didn't considered that `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called multiple times. Maybe thats my mistake. Sure, I added my current code to the question. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: If you're setting your keyboard's frame, how/where are you setting it? And yes, your button will be added multiple times with different frames each time viewDidLayoutSubviews is called, so you may be added more buttons than you realize.

Comment: I don't set my keyboards frame at all. I just add the subviews to the normal view/keyboardView. My keyboard has the same size as the default iOS keyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131981/discussion-between-lyndsey-scott-and-paro).